How to Write a Monad in Haskell to Track and Prefetch i18n Keys Efficiently?
I'm trying to write a Monad that tracks which i18n keys are being used by a piece of code. The idea is to pre-fetch values of all those keys in an efficient manner beforehand, rather than end-up with an "N+1" situation during code execution.
Here's what I have till now (code given at the end). How do I write the Monad instance for this? Is it even possible? Is there any other idea to do this? I'm fine with tracking the keys at the type-level as well, as long as the devex/ergonomics are manageable.
The other way I'm thinking about this is, that I need the code to run in "two phases":

The first phase conceptually returns two values: [I18nKey] - the list of i18n keys the code depends upon and [(I18nKey, I18nStr)] -> m Text an un-applied function which needs the i18n keys in an assoc-list to generate the final value.
The second phases fetches converts [I18nKey] -> [(I18nKey, I18nStr)] using a single DB query and applies them to the function to get the final value.

How do I express the above in Haskell code in an ergonomic manner?
import UnliftIO.IORef
import Data.Text
import Control.Monad.Reader
import qualified Data.List as DL

type I18nKey = Text
type I18nStr = Text

data I18nEnv m a = I18nEnv
  { envI18nExpectedKeys :: [I18nKey]
  , envI18nVal :: ReaderT [(I18nKey, I18nStr)] m a
  }

instance (Functor m) => Functor (I18nEnv m) where
  {-# INLINE fmap #-}
  fmap f env = 
    env{envI18nVal=fmap f (envI18nVal env)}

instance (Applicative m) => Applicative (I18nEnv m) where
  {-# INLINE pure #-}
  pure x = 
    I18nEnv { envI18nExpectedKeys = [], envI18nVal = pure x }

  {-# INLINE (<*>) #-}
  (<*>) fn a = I18nEnv
    { envI18nExpectedKeys=(envI18nExpectedKeys fn <> envI18nExpectedKeys a)
    , envI18nVal=(envI18nVal fn) <*> (envI18nVal a)
    }

Attempt at writing realistic code to solve this problem
Note: this doesn't compile
import Lucid
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM
import UnlifIO
import Data.Set (Set)

type I18nKey = Text -- eg en.user_greeting
type I18NInterpolation = Text -- eg. "Hello {{ username }}"
type I18nReplacements = [(Text, Text)] -- eg [("username", "john doe"), ("email", "johndoe@gmail.com")]

data HtmlCtx = HtmlCtx 
  { ctxI18nKeysetRef :: !(IORef (Set I18nKey))
  } deriving (Eq, Show)
$(makeLensesWith abbreviatedFields ''HtmlCtx)


translate :: I18nKey -> I18nReplacements -> HM.HashMap I18nKey I18NInterpolation -> Text
translate = undefined

newtype UnappliedI18n a = UnappliedI18n { rawUnappliedI18n :: HM.HashMap I18nKey I18NInterpolation -> a } deriving (Generic, Functor, Applicative, Monad, Semigroup, Monoid)

newtype I18nHtml a 
  = I18nHtml { rawI18nHtml :: HtmlT (ReaderT HtmlCtx IO) (UnappliedI18n a) }
    deriving (Generic, Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader HtmlCtx)


A thought experiment: I suppose you have something like fetch :: I18nKey -> I18nEnv I18nStr. What keys should envI18nExpectedKeys (fetch "foo" >>= fetch) have? (And no, unfortunately you cannot avoid this problem just by invalidating the equality I18nKey ~ I18nStr -- simply write any other nontrivial function bar :: I18nStr -> I18nKey and we're back in business with fetch "foo" >>= fetch . bar.)

You can have a monad if you're willing to draw a type-level distinction between values you have now and values you will only have in the future. Here's a sketch to give you the idea:
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Maybe
import Data.String

type Key = String
type Value = String

getFromDB :: [Key] -> IO [Value]
getFromDB = undefined

newtype Future a = Future ([(Key, Value)] -> a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, Semigroup, Monoid)
instance IsString a => IsString (Future a) where fromString = pure . fromString

fetch :: MonadWriter [Key] m => Key -> m (Future Value)
fetch k = Future (fromJust . lookup k) <$ tell [k]

i18n :: WriterT [Key] IO (Future a) -> IO a
i18n act = do
  (Future f, ks) <- runWriterT act
  vs <- getFromDB ks
  pure (f (zip ks vs))

exampleAction :: WriterT [Key] IO (Future Value)
exampleAction = do
  namePrompt <- fetch "name prompt"
  addressPrompt <- fetch "address prompt"
  pure $ ""
    <> "<label>" <> namePrompt <> "</label><textarea id=\"name\"/>"
    <> "<label>" <> addressPrompt <> "</label><textarea id=\"address\"/>"

Of course you'll want to do all the usual software engineering things: make a custom transformer, mtl-style class, use better data structures than lists and strings, use one of the modern WriterTs, have some sort of error handling, etc. but I trust you know how to flesh out all those details.

Yes, this encapsulates my idea about the "two phase" execution, but conceptually isn't Future a basically a Reader? Why is this not possible with a Reader and Writer stacked on top of each other?

@SaurabhNanda Yep, conceptually it's a Reader. There's two differences from the stack. 1. WriterT w (Reader r) a and ReaderT r (Writer w) a are both r -> (w, a), but this is (w, r -> a). 2. The stack -- and your sample code -- does not permit non-Future return values, i.e. (w, a) in the previous difference's nomenclature. (...and so the Monad instance is forced to attempt to handle the Readery bits.)

I'm back to solving this problem and struggling with implementing your suggested idea in my real-life monad stack. Could you please take a look at the second code snippet that I've added to the question. Thanks, much appreciated!

@SaurabhNanda You have once again attempted to avoid having a type-level distinction between now and the future. You must remove the UnappliedI18n from inside the definition of I18nHtml so that you can have both the types I18nHtml a for things you have now and I18nHtml (UnappliedI18n a) for things you will have later.

It's not possible. Forgetting about the ReaderT for a moment, your type is basically ([I18nKey], m a); in order to make this a monad you would have to implement join :: ([I18nKey], m ([I18nKey], m a)) → ([I18nKey], m a), but there is no way to extract the inner [I18nKey] from under m in general.
The correct way to combine a general monad m with Writer [I18nKey] is to use WriterT [I18nKey] m, which instead translates to m ([I18nKey], a), but it doesn't seem like this suits your use case.
Are you sure you need a monad? It would help to see an example of how you intend to use this monad.
